# IDE Suggestion for python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ide

I am using python for web programming and javascript heavily. Currently, i am using NetBeans 
but i am looking for another IDE. NetBeans is not very good while programming with python and javascript. Any suggestion?

Comment: WebStorm from www.jetbrains.com is excellent for JavaScript, because it supports ECMAScript 5, understands JsDoc perfectly (inheritance and all). It's the only IDE that actually does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) has support for both Python and Javascript.
2. JetBrains' [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is good for Python <strike>but I don't think</strike> and it supports Javascript.
3. If you don't mind using [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) then use [Pydev](http://pydev.org/) for Python and get a suitable plugin for Javascript.
4. (Thanks [@deif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225970/deif)) There is also [Aptana](http://aptana.com). Aptana is based on Eclipse which means that it will support PyDev. It has better JS support too.
5. **Update** You probably know this, but I'll say it for the record. Don't forget the classic editors viz. [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [Vi(m)](http://www.vim.org/). They have a steeper learning curve compared to the other editors listed above but the rewards of mastery are exponentially bigger.

Comment: as an alternative to point 3, you migth want to look at aptana (http://www.aptana.com). aptana is based on eclipse, so all eclipse plugins includig pydev, of course, should work as well. the difference is that aptana ships with (imho) nicer html and javascript support.

Answer (score 1):

You could try  the version of [eclipse for javascript](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr) and just add the [pydev plugin](http://pydev.org/) for python development.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm (and other IDEs on IDEA platform) is brilliant IDE for python, js, xml, css and other languages in webdev stack.

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse with Pydev (Python) and Aptana (Javascript) plugins

Answer (score 1):

This is not an IDE, it's just a code editor but after installing some extensions, it's perfect. You can try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite IDE, but on MacOSX i'm using TextMate, it have many extensions which makes it very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

For web programming I used Espresso, it only work on Mac but it is quite good,this one is an IDE.

I don't think the rest classify as an IDE.

For python I use sublimetext2 because it can be customize and has a great GUI feel.

I used to use notepad++ don't really suggest it.

I think if you are asking for efficiency use vim.